# I have a unlimited vpn and a 2GB isp. can i use my vpn without using the 2 gig limit on my ISP?

Tags: vpn

I have a 2gig telstra prepaid wifi. The VPN I am using is unlimited. when I download it comes off both my VPN and ISP. Is it possible to set it up so it only uses my VPN download ratio.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not possible, your wifi is the connection you are using regardless

Answer (score 2):

No. Your VPN data goes over your wireless connection, so it will be counted like any other data. Your provider's data limits will apply regardless.